# Angular pipe toLocaleUpperCase

Tags: angular, pipe, uppercase

It's my pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'transformFullName'
})
export class TransformFullNamePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, ...args: unknown[]): string {
    let fullName: string[] = value.split(' ');
    fullName[0].charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase();
    fullName[1].charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase();
    console.log(fullName);
    if (fullName[0].length + fullName[1].length > 41) {
      return fullName[0].charAt(0) + '. ' + fullName[1].charAt(0) + '.';
    }
    return fullName[0] + ' ' + fullName[1];
  }

}
```

I get on consoles:

```
(2) ["male", "male"]
0: "male"
1: "male"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

and one error: core.js:6157 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
at TransformFullNamePipe.transform (transform-full-name.pipe.ts:11). Why?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz

Comment: I think that the error comes from the spaces in  the string without second name. To solve it you can add `trim` like that `value.trim().split(' ');` - see comment below

Comment: @Szyszka947 Also, check for the length of the fullName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is pipe in Angular - `titlecase`:

```
{{'tHIs is mIXeD CaSe' | titlecase}}
<!-- output is expected to be "This Is Mixed Case" -->
```

https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe

I think this is what you tried to do:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'transformFullName'
})
export class TransformFullNamePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): string {
    const fullName: string[] = value.trim().split(' ');
    fullName[0] = fullName[0].charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase();
    fullName[1] = fullName[1].charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase();
    console.log(fullName);
    if (fullName[0].length + fullName[1].length > 41) {
      return fullName[0].charAt(0) + '. ' + fullName[1].charAt(0) + '.';
    }
    return fullName[0] + ' ' + fullName[1];
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know this pipe :D!

Answer (score 0):

you are not assigning the values to `fullName[0]` and `fullName[1]`.
you should do :

```
fullName[0] = fullName[0].charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase();
fullName[1] = fullName[1].charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase();
```

here is an example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-pipes-slnu4k?file=app/exponential-strength.pipes.ts